# How fast can we find all Four-Square combinations that sum to N?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, number-theory, enumeration

A question was asked at Stack Overflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11732555/how-to-find-all-possible-values-of-four-variables-when-squared-sum-to-n#comment15599644_11732555):

> Given an integer $N$, print out all possible combinations of integer values of $A,B,C$ and $D$ which solve the equation $A^2+B^2+C^2+D^2 = N$.

This question is of course related to [Bachet's Conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_four-square_theorem) in number theory (sometimes called Lagrange's Four Square Theorem because of his proof).  There are some papers that discuss how to find a single solution, but I have been unable to find anything that talks about how fast we can find *all* solutions for a particular $N$ (that is, all *combinations*, not all *permutations*).

I have been thinking about it quite a bit and it seems to me that it can be solved in $O(N)$ time and space, where $N$ is the desired sum. However, lacking any prior information on the subject, I am not sure if that is a significant claim on my part or just a trivial, obvious or already known result.

So, the question then is, how fast can we find all of the Four-Square Sums for a given $N$?

---

OK, here's the (nearly) $O(N)$ algorithm that I was thinking of.  First two supporting functions, a nearest integer square root function:

```
// The nearest integer whose square is less than or equal to N
public int SquRt(int N) {
    return (int) Math.Sqrt((double) N);
}
```

And a function to return all TwoSquare pairs summing from 0 to N:

```
// Returns a list of all sums of two squares less than or equal to N, in order.
public List<List<int[]>> TwoSquareSumsLessThan(int N) {
    // Make the index array
    List<int[]>[] Sum2Sqs = new List<int[]>[N + 1];

    // Get the base square root, which is the maximum possible root value
    int baseRt = SquRt(N);
    for (int i = baseRt; i >= 0; i--) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
            int sum = (i * i) + (j * j);
            if (sum > N) {
                break;
            } else {
                // Make the new pair
                int[] sumPair = { i, j };
                // Get the sumList entry
                List<int[]> sumLst;
                if (Sum2Sqs[sum] == null) {   
                    // make it if we need to
                    sumLst = new List<int[]>();
                    Sum2Sqs[sum] = sumLst;
                } else {
                    sumLst = Sum2Sqs[sum];
                }

                // Add the pair to the correct list
                sumLst.Add(sumPair);
            }
        }
    }

    // Collapse the index array down to a sequential list
    List<List<int[]>> result = new List<List<int[]>>();
    for (int nn = 0; nn <= N; nn++) {
        if (Sum2Sqs[nn] != null)
            result.Add(Sum2Sqs[nn]);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Finally, the algorithm itself:

```
// Return a list of all integer quads (a,b,c,d), where:
//      a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 = N,
// and  a >= b >= c >= d,
// and  a,b,c,d >= 0
public List<int[]> FindAllFourSquares(int N) {
    // get all two-square sums <= N, in descending order
    List<List<int[]>> Sqr2s = TwoSquareSumsLessThan(N);

    // Cross the descending list of two-square sums <= N with
    // the same list in ascending order, using a Merge-Match
    // algorithm to find all combinations of pairs of two-square
    // sums that add up to N
    List<int[]> hiList, loList;
    int[] hp, lp;
    int hiSum, loSum;
    List<int[]> results = new List<int[]>();
    int prevHi = -1, prevLo = -1;

    // Set the Merge sources to the highest and lowest entries in the list
    int hi = Sqr2s.Count - 1;
    int lo = 0;

    //  Merge until done ..
    while (hi >= lo) {
        // check to see if the points have moved
        if (hi != prevHi) {
            hiList = Sqr2s[hi];
            hp = hiList[0];     // these lists cannot be empty
            hiSum = hp[0] * hp[0] + hp[1] * hp[1];
            prevHi = hi;
        }

        if (lo != prevLo) {
            loList = Sqr2s[lo];
            lp = loList[0];     // these lists cannot be empty
            loSum = lp[0] * lp[0] + lp[1] * lp[1];
            prevLo = lo;
        }

        // Do the two entries' sums together add up to N?
        if (hiSum + loSum == N) {
            // they add up, so cross the two sum-lists over each other
            foreach (int[] hiPair in hiList) {
                foreach (int[] loPair in loList) {
                    // Make a new 4-tuple and fill it
                    int[] quad = new int[4];
                    quad[0] = hiPair[0];
                    quad[1] = hiPair[1];
                    quad[2] = loPair[0];
                    quad[3] = loPair[1];

                    // Only keep those cases where the tuple is already sorted
                    //(Otherwise it's a duplicate entry)
                    if (quad[1] >= quad[2]) { // (only need to check this one case, the others are implicit)
                        results.Add(quad);
                    }

                    // (there's a special case where all values of the 4-tuple are equal
                    // that should be handled to prevent duplicate entries, but I'm
                    // skipping it for now)
                }
            }

            // Both the HI and LO points must be moved after a Match
            hi--;
            lo++;
        } else if (hiSum + loSum < N) {
            lo++; // too low, so must increase the LO point
        } else { // must be > N
            hi--;   // too high, so must decrease the HI point
        }
    }

    return results;
}
```

As I said before, it should be pretty close to $O(N)$. However, as Yuval Filmus points out, as the number of Four Square solutions to N can be of order $N.ln(ln(N))$, then this algorithim could not be less than that.

Comment: Yes, please post it.  I'm still developing the linear algorithm details, but I'm pretty sure it's valid.

Comment: For the record, it appears that sometimes there are as many as $\Omega(N\log\log N)$ solutions, so we can't really have an $O(N)$ algorithm.

Comment: From here, it looks like the catch (and the extra non-linear factor) comes from the two foreach() loops within your main while loop; your total time is basically $\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{N/2} |hiList_{N-i}|*|loList_i|$, and the problem is that the sizes of hiList and loList aren't necessarily bounded by any constant.

Comment: Yes, that's correct, however your formula's a little bit off because first i ranges from 0 to apprx. N*PI/8, and second only a fraction of the values of i satisfy hiList(N-i)+loList(i) = N, so they are not all added in.  In any event, there's no way to fix this and I am pretty sure that this gives the minimum possible complexity of O(N*log(log(N))).

Comment: But we can have an algorithm that runs in O (max (N, "number of solutions")), taking O (n) space.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Juho's algorithm can be improved to an $O(N)$ algorithm using meet-in-the-middle. Go over all pairs $A,B \leq \sqrt{N}$; for each pair such that $M=A^2+B^2 \leq N$, store $(A,B)$ in some array $T$ of length $N$ (each position $M$ could contain several pairs, which might be stored in a linked list). Now go over pairs $M,N-M$ such that the corresponding cells in $T$ are non-empty.

This way we get an implicit representation of all quadruples. If we want to list all of them, then we can't do any better than $\Omega(N\log\log N)$, since [Jacobi's four square theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_four-square_theorem) shows that (for odd $N$) the number of representations is $8\sigma(N)$, and there are infinitely many integers such that $\sigma(N) \geq (e^\gamma - \epsilon) N\log\log N$ (see [Grönwall's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6nwall%27s_theorem#Gr.C3.B6nwall.27s_theorem)).

In order to get less trivial algorithms, one can try to factor $N$ over the appropriate quaternion ring, since we know that the representations as sums of two squares correspond (in some sense) to these factorizations, through Lagrange's four-square identity. We would still need to find all representations of any relevant prime.

Comment: Hmm, the meet-in-the-middle thing sounds very similar to what I am working on (almost done) which is an ascending/descending Merge-Match algorithm over the TwoSquare pairs.  Does that sound the same?

Comment: It's probably the same, meet-in-the-middle is such a common heuristic that it must have many different names.

Comment: Umm, I've been out of academia for thirty years, what's the $\sigma(N)$ thing mean? (or can you point me to a reference?) thnx.

Comment: Or is that $\sigma(N)$ really a $\omicron(N)$?

Comment: Ah I see, it's the SumOfDivisors function?

Comment: Sum of divisors function indeed.

Answer (score 5):

The obvious algorithm that runs in quadratic time enumerates all tuples $A,B,C,D \leq \sqrt[]{N}$. This can be done in four loops, so the total time complexity becomes $O(N^2)$. It also clearly enumerates all solutions.

As relating algorithms, Rabin and Shallit [1] present two randomized algorithms for decomposing integers as sum of squares. For two squares, they give a $O(\log^2 n)$ expected time algorithm. For four squares, they give a $O(\log^2 n \log \log n)$ expected time algorithm. Note that the algorithms don't give you *all* the solutions, but merely just one.

---

[1] [M. O. Rabin, J. O. Shallit, *Randomized Algorithms in Number Theory*, Communications on Pure and Applied Mathematics 39 (1986), no. S1, pp. S239–S256](http://dx.doi.org/10.1002%2Fcpa.3160390713).

Comment: For a trivial algorithm, you only need loops for A, B, and C and then calculate D and check it is an integer. If you require A ≤ B ≤ C ≤ D you should get O (N^1.5) with a rather small constant.

Comment: About 0.04 N^1.5 triples (A, B, C), and checking that N - A^2 - B^2 - C^2 is a square can be done very quickly.

Answer (score -2):

The number of solutions is exactly $8\sum d$, where $d$ goes over all divisors of $n$ which are not multiples of 4. This is a [theorem of Jacobi.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi's_four-square_theorem)

Comment: And how does this answer the question? The task is to give all these quadruples!

Comment: This is already mentioned in my answer.