# Finding the sum of four squares

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, number-theory

There is [Lagrange's four-square theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange's_four-square_theorem), which statea that

> Given an integer $N$, we can write $N$ as a sum of four squares
>   $A^2+B^2+C^2+D^2=N$.

How can I find a valid solution with time complexity of $O(1)$ or $O(\sqrt N)$? I only have to find one solution.

Here is my $O(1)$ algorithm:

```
while(count!=4){
     solution = sqrt(N)
     print solution
     N-= solution*solution
     count++       
}
```

But it does not works for all $N$, for example it fails for $N=23$. Is there any other solution?

Comment: [Closely related question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2988/how-fast-can-we-find-all-four-square-combinations-that-sum-to-n); duplicate?

Comment: See also http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/68501/755, http://stackoverflow.com/q/41524508/781723, http://mathoverflow.net/q/259152/37212, http://math.stackexchange.com/q/366673/14578, http://math.stackexchange.com/q/483101/14578, http://mathoverflow.net/q/110239/37212.

Answer (score 4):

Try this: [Legendre's_three-square_theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre's_three-square_theorem)

Assume $4\not\mid N$. If not, divide $N$ by $4^k$ and multiply $2^k$ back in the end. Find an $A$ satisfying $N-A^2\not\equiv0,4,7 \mod 8$. It's always valid to choose $A=\lfloor\sqrt{N}\rfloor$ or $\lfloor\sqrt{N}\rfloor-1$. (Choose the even one if $N\equiv 1,5 \mod 8$ and the odd one otherwise.) Now $N-A^2$ is an integer in $O(\sqrt{N})$ and you can find $B,C,D$ in $O(\sqrt{N})$ easily.

Edit: Since $B,C,D\le cN^{\frac{1}{4}}$ for some small constant $c$, we can enumerate two of them (suppose $B$ and $C$) and check whether the corresponding $D$ is an integer. This works in $O(\sqrt{N})$. There might be some faster solutions.

Comment: Couldn't figure out for ages how you can find B, C, D in O ($N^{1/2}$). But that is obviously because $B^2+C^2+D^2 ≤ O(N^{1/2})$, so B, C, D ≤ $O(N^{1/4})$...

Answer (score -2):

I am going to provide you with 4 links and I hope it will help you.

this one is an online calculator based on an algorithm from math overflow.

http://www.mathcelebrity.com/foursquare.php?num=+178&pl=Show+Lagrange+Four-Square+Notation

the math overflow algorithm can be found here.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11732555/how-to-find-all-possible-values-of-four-variables-when-squared-sum-to-n

and then there is also this algorithm from cs stackexchange

[How fast can we find all Four-Square combinations that sum to N?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2988/how-fast-can-we-find-all-four-square-combinations-that-sum-to-n)

and if you want to do a bit of work, then there is this algorithm that can find the sum of 2 squares for a given integer. So you would have to divide your number in two ( not necessarily equal part ) and then add up the results to get a 4 square representation.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1972771/is-this-the-general-solution-of-finding-the-two-original-squares-that-add-up-to/1977767?noredirect=1#comment4062390_1977767

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: This answer also appears at http://mathoverflow.net/a/259203/37212.